# How to remove the diagnostic content on hover in my VS Code extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my VS Code extension, I have registered a command to remove a diagnostic:

`extension.ts`

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        DELETE_DIAGNOSTIC_COMMAND, 
        () => removeDiagnostic()
    )
);
```

This is what the `removeDiagnostic` function looks like:

`utils.ts`

```
export function removeDiagnostic(): void {
    const editor = window.activeTextEditor;
    if(editor){
        const diagnosticStart = editor.selection.start;
        const diagnosticEnd = editor.selection.end;
        const diagnosticRange = new Range(diagnosticStart, diagnosticEnd);
        editor.edit(editBuilder => {
            editBuilder.replace(diagnosticRange, "");
        });
}
```

The `DELETE_DIAGNOSTIC_COMMAND` is provided here as a code action:

`MyCodeActionProvider.ts`

```
const DELETE_DIAGNOSTIC_COMMAND = 'delete-diagnostic.command';

export class MyCodeActionProvider implements vscode.CodeActionProvider {

    public static readonly providedCodeActionKinds = [
        vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix
    ];

    provideCodeActions(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range | vscode.Selection, context: vscode.CodeActionContext, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.CodeAction[] {
        return context.diagnostics
            .filter(diagnostic => diagnostic.code === 'myDiagnosticCode')
            .map(diagnostic => this.createCommandCodeAction(diagnostic));
    }

    private createCommandCodeAction(diagnostic: vscode.Diagnostic): vscode.CodeAction {
        const action = new vscode.CodeAction('Remove deprecated intrinsic', vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
        action.command = { command: DELETE_DIAGNOSTIC_COMMAND, title: 'Remove deprecated intrinsic', tooltip: 'This will remove the deprecated intrinsic from the editor.' };
        action.diagnostics = [diagnostic];
        action.isPreferred = true;
        return action;
    }
}
```

And, the code actions provider is registered here:

`extension.ts`

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.languages.registerCodeActionsProvider('myFileExtension', new MyCodeActionProvider(), {
        providedCodeActionKinds: MyCodeActionProvider.providedCodeActionKinds
    })
);
```

In the `removeDiagnostic` function, I want to get the diagnostic's range when I hover on the diagnostic, in order to run the quick-fix command to remove it.

To be more clear, when I run the command from the `Problems` tab, I am able to remove the selected range, but not when I hover on the diagnostic:

[image: code-action-command]

How can I remove the diagnostic from the editor when I run the command after I hover on it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass the diagnostic from the code action to your `DELETE_DIAGNOSTIC_COMMAND` command in the `args` property and use the `range` property of the diagnostic in the command

Comment: Hmm, could you please provide a snippet based on my code above? I am not sure I understand how to use the `range` property elsewhere.

Comment: @6cloud9 The diagnostic object has a range, just make sure it ends in the command that needs it as an argument.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer isn't much use unless you already know what the answer is. Make sure "the range" ends in the command that needs it?!? I'm sure it's perfectly clear if you're intimately familiar with VSCode but for me looking for the same answer the OP needed, it's zero help.

Comment: @Basic Read the VSC API and the example extensions, that is the information I used

Comment: So your answer is incomplete and depends upon other resources you've neither linked nor quoted? I'm surprised I have to point a 20k user at this but ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . In any case, I've made my point and don't want to pile on, so I shall leave this as-is and not respond again. All the best.